# JTable Columns not appearing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, event-dispatching

I am trying to display a simple jtable in frame but It is not displaying the columns of the table, I followed the example from the oracle tutorials but there is something I am not doing right. The program is compiling and running. Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel 
{

    SimpleTableDemo()
    {
        String[] columnNames = {"#",
                "Repayment Dates",
                "Principle Amount",
                "Interest",
                "Comission fee",
                "Total installement amount", 
                "Principle balance"};

//      BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        //each line of the two dimentional array is a line in the table
        Object[][] data = {
                {new Integer(1), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(2), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(3), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(4), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(5), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(6), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(7), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(8), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(9), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(10), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(11), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(12), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(13), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(14), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(15), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(16), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(17), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
                {new Integer(18), new java.util.Date(), new BigDecimal(12509.23).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(1571.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(0.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(14081.00).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), new BigDecimal(147490.77).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)},
            };


        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

//      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
//      scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
//      scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);    
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        this.add(table);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        SimpleTableDemo panel = new SimpleTableDemo();
        application.add(panel);
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//      application.setSize(730,650);
        application.pack();
        application.setLocationRelativeTo(panel);
//      application.setResizable(false);
        application.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Table columns are only automatically displayed if the `JTable` is inside a `JScrollPane`.
Instead of `this.add(table);`, try `this.add(new JScrollPane(table));`

Actually, you seem to have some scrollpane-related code lying about already - just uncomment `JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);` and change `this.add(table);` to `this.add(scrollpane);`

Answer (score 3):

Having a `JScrollPane` always helps. You already have the following code:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

All you need to do is add your `JTable` to this `scrollpane`.

However,I would suggest that any updates to the user interface to happen on the **event dispatch thread**. Basically, instead of having this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        SimpleTableDemo panel = new SimpleTableDemo();
        application.add(panel);
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//      application.setSize(730,650);
        application.pack();
        application.setLocationRelativeTo(panel);
//      application.setResizable(false);
        application.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Consider:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame application = new JFrame();
                SimpleTableDemo panel = new SimpleTableDemo();
                application.add(panel);
                application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            //      application.setSize(730,650);
                application.pack();
                application.setLocationRelativeTo(panel);
            //      application.setResizable(false);
                application.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
}
```

[This article](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml) might help you understand the concept of "Threading with Swing"

Comment: ehh .. not completely correct: _all_ access - including instantiation - must happen on the EDT (as correctly done in the referenced link :-)